# What's the relationship between c# and asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Are the two the same thing or ?

Answer (score 12):

No.

C# is a **language**.

ASP.Net is a **[Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_framework)** for building Web Applications. Which is a set of classes/methods than can speed up development and you would use C# to access these classes and call those methods.

You could use ASP.Net with C# or Visual Basic. You can also use C# without ASP.Net.

Comment: can I still use other languages, or is ASP.net wed to C#? In ancient ASP scripting, I last used that ca. 9 years ago, there were choices.

Comment: Yes. You can use other languages such as Visual Basic

Comment: You *can* use VB.NET to develop your ASP.NET application. The choice is yours. *hypnotic voice: C#, C#, C#..*

Comment: You can use any number of .NET languages to develop your application - even if the help you get for languages other than C# or VB.NET is limited in the front end web project most of the *work* should be in other projects (assemblies) and that gives you a lot of flexibility

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET is a framework (with libraries and a bunch of controls) related to web applications and web sites. C# is one of the languages to use within the ASP.NET framework.

Similarly, you can use different languages, like C# or VB.NET for WinForms development. Same idea for ASP.NET.